Парсинг сайтов fetch/xhr
После загрузки страницы, сайт отправляет запросы fetch/xhr.
Мне нужно как то извлечь их json файл используя selenium. Вопрос только как?


Нужно анализировать данные на странице, так что думайте.

Да просто через requests такой же запрос отправить, сразу json получите. Единственно, нужно смотреть как там авторизация работает, в headers возможно токен передается или что-то такое.

используете ли моки/прокси? Можешь посмотреть в сторону сохранения запросов в HAR, с дальнейшим извлечением запросов из него
